# Create listview on code behind in WP 8.1

Tags: listview

I am new to Windows phone 8.1 app development. What I am trying to do is create a listview with a textblock and a button entirely from code behind in c#.I have the data pulled in from the SQLite database, which is mapped to a class to an observable collection. I want the listview to be bound to this collection and the textblock inside the listview should be bound to one of the properties inside the observable collection which is bound to the listview. This is where I have reached so far, by stitching in pieces of code from the internet. It doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't produce the actual result.

```
private void LoadListView()
    {
        ListView lvSchedule = new ListView();
        TextBlock tbDate = new TextBlock();
        tbDate.FontSize = 50;
        //tbDate.HorizontalAlignment = "Left";
        tbDate.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];

        Binding bind = new Binding();
       // bind.Path
        tbDate.Text = "{Binding Date}";

        lvSchedule.Items.Add(tbDate);
        lvSchedule.ItemsSource = theSchedulesOC;

        firstPivotItem.Content = lvSchedule;
    }
```

Please advise.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the binding is wrong. You have to create a Binding object.

This wont work:
    tbDate.Text = "{Binding Date}";

You can see a very good example here:
[How to: Create a Binding in Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx)
The problem in your case is that you will need to create a DataTemplate from the code behind.

It would be better if you do all in the XAML like this:

```
<ListBox name="lvSchedule">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" >
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then in the code behind you just do this:

```
lvSchedule.ItemsSource = theSchedulesOC;
```

Comment: Oh ok. I checked the link, but I am confused how would I bind the textblock to one of the fields in the observable collection.

Comment: You will have to create a DataTemplate object and assign that to your ListBox.ItemTemplate. However, I am afraid you cannot create templates from code but from XAML.

Comment: Oh is it. I didn't know that we cannot create datatemplates in code. Moving onto xaml then. Thanks CCamilo.